# How do I append to a text file from an input on an html razor page?

Tags: javascript, html, razor-pages

I am trying to append `urls` entered from an HTML input into a text file. I want to do it in `javascript` but I don't have much practice with it. I have what my code looks like right now. I know its wrong, I am just so lost right now I don't know where to start.

```html
<form>
    <div class="textBox">
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="InputLink" placeholder="Enter a valid link" runat="server"/>
        <br />
        <button id="uploadBtn" type="submit" onclick="UploadButton_Click()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#saveToFile').click(function (e) {
            var url = document.getElementByID('InputLink').value;
            StreamWriter writer1 = new StreamWriter("log.txt");
            writer1.WriteLine(url);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: looks like you're mixing C# in to the JavaScript. You can't do this.

Comment: are you developper php or nodejs